# Using multiple themes on a single site in Magnolia

Tags: templates, content-management-system, themes, nodes, magnolia

I am looking for a way to use multiple themes at the same time on a single site installation (Magnolia CE). Is this even possible or do I have to use some kind of a workaround?

The only place I found to assign a theme is `Site definitions` > `theme` > `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple themes are available only in Enterprise Edition.